# Regex optional character with a conditional clause

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex problem that combines the ideas of optional characters and conditional regex statements that I'm unsure how to solve.

I want to find a pattern that, in addition to matching an initial number, will also match the following uppercase letter if and only if that character is not followed by a lowercase letter. The string will only ever have one number. For example:

```
'fds;o2Ko ' ==> '2'
'rejy 3ked' ==> '3'
's.fg6G hb' ==> '6G'
'3M- gfafg' ==> '3M'
'dgfAN adg' ==> no pattern found
```

I've tried various combinations of conditional statements but can't seem to combine the concepts properly. I'm working in python using the following code:

```
pattern = r'[1-9][A-Z]?' 
ID = str(re.findall(pattern, 's.fg6G hb')).strip('[]\'')
```

The above is what I want without the conditional statement. I'm unsure how to include an appropriate conditional statement. I think pattern would be something like `r'[1-9](?(?=[A-Z][a-z])[A-Z]?|)'` but don't understand how I can look ahead beyond the current character.

Comment: *"I've tried various combinations"*; Can you share some of these attempts, just so this question would not be off-topic? Also, what environment are you using?

Comment: @JvdV I'm working in python and searching using the following code:
`pattern = r'[1-9][A-Z]?'`
`ID = str(re.findall(pattern, 's.fg6G hb')).strip('[]\'')`
The above is what I want without the conditional statement. I'm unsure how to include an appropriate conditional statement. I think pattern would be something like `r'[1-9](?(?=[A-Z][a-z])[A-Z]?|)'` but don't understand how I can look ahead beyond the current character.

Comment: You should update your actual question with your attempt. Not all will read comments. Either way, I posten my attempt at solving your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can try to use:

```
\d+(?:[A-Z](?![a-z]))?
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rUVj2l/1)

- `\d+` - 1+ Digits.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `[A-Z]` - A single uppercase alpha.
  - `(?![a-z])` - A nested negative lookahead to assert position is not followed by a lowercase alpha.
  - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to understand. The resource you linked is also very helpful.